# I still can't understand what does Community Wiki do?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have read Help Center and immunity FAQ, but I still can't understand Community Wiki, I mean, isn't reputation the most important factor on this site, and by denying giving reputation to Community Wiki, it seems unfair. Why would SE create Community Wiki mode?

Comment: Community wiki is there to say 'hey, this post does not belong to any single user. This was something made by many people in the community', or 'hey, I want low reputation users to be able to help contribute to this post without review process.'

Comment: @michaelb958 I have read that post but I still can't understand the function of Community Wiki.

Comment: @3ventic That's the purpose? Not because the question is very soft? In mathSE, the Community Wiki questions are almost all soft-qeustions.

Comment: @AveMaleficum Look at the section "**How do Community Wiki posts work?**". It demonstrates the *effects*, which should help. For example, voting on CW posts doesn't affect anyone's reputation.

Comment: @michaelb958 I think the reason they create CW is most CW questions are easy to answer, so the high votes question owner will get a high reputation he doesn't deserve. And SE won't let this kind of thing happen, because high reputation user will have much more privilege.